# AG Grid - Display Dropdown outside the grid boundary

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, overflow, ag-grid

I am using React AgGrid and have a custom cell renderer that displays a dropdown.
I can get the dropdown to display over the rows below but the dropdown clips at the bottom edge of the grid.

How can I get the dropdown to show outside the bottom edge of AG Grid?

A code sandbox example would be very helpful.

Comment: Could you provide a code sandbox example of your current code as a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

```
.ag-body-viewport {
    overflow: visible;
}

.ag-root,
.ag-root-wrapper, 
.ag-center-cols-clipper, 
.ag-center-cols-viewport,
.ag-body-viewport-wrapper {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

This maintains the scrollbar